# Why is radius set to 0.0 in one line and then to an input value in the next?

Tags: python

This was one of the code I met.

```
    pi=3.414
    def area(r):
       return (pi*r*r)
    def circumference:
       return (pi*2*r)
    radius=0.0
    radius=float(raw_input("Enter radius: "))
    print "area",area(radius)
    print "circumference",circumference(radius)
```

what is the need of radius=0.0? One of my friends said that it would prevent garbage collection. But I don't understand how would it prevent that.....

Comment: Surely you can dream up a title which summarizes your question.

Comment: `pi=3.414`?  Circles must be strangely shaped in your world. :-)

Comment: Maybe OP is from Texas? I hear everything is bigger in Texas.

Comment: "One of my friends said that it would prevent garbage collection" 0_o Ask your friend why on Earth he/she would believe that.

Comment: @DSM It's just a typo... :c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`radius = 0.0` creates the variable `radius` as a float, but that's unnecessary, because the very next line overwrites it's previous assignment with a new assignment. Which is to say, it has no current purpose and can safely be removed.

The rest of your code has problems also: `def circumference:` needs `()`, but also needs an argument inside them: `(r)`. Running the code currently returns SyntaxError: invalid syntax.

The easy fix is: `def circumference(r):`

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for `radius=0.0`. It is completely superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

1. No need of `radius=0.0` statement because in next statement new `radius` variable is created.

We can check by `id` method. In following example I have created two variables with same name.

```
>>> radius=0.0
>>> id(radius)
158012196
>>> radius=10.0
>>> id(radius)
158012180
>>>
```

2. Argument is missing in function `circumference`. Change to

code:

```
def circumference(r):
       return (pi*2*r)
```

3. Use exception handling on user enter value.

code:

```
>>> try:
...     radius=float(raw_input("Enter radius: "))
... except ValueError:
...    print "Enter value is not float."
...    radius=1.0
... 
Enter radius: e
Enter value is not float.
```

4. Value of `pi` is `3.14159`. Check by python `math` library.

code:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.pi
3.141592653589793
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The only reason to use `radius = 0.0` is as a fallback method in case the following line fails. However, the line afterwards is

```
radius=float(raw_input("Enter radius: "))
```

which only fails when the input cannot be converted to a float type. Such as with either of the following:

```
# Generates a ValueError since the string isn't parseable
float("Hello, World!")

# Generates a TypeError since the argument isn't of type string or a number
float([5])
```

Unfortunately, you will find that this not only fails, but stops Python from continuing to execute.

In order to get around this issue, I would recommend wrapping raw user input that one is immediately casting to a numeric type in a try statement, such as the following:

```
try:
    radius=float(raw_input("Enter radius: "))
except (TypeError, ValueError):
    radius=0.0
```

This will catch both types of parsing errors (though, strictly, only `ValueError` will ever occur since the return value is a string, but this serves as a good example of multiple error catching) and assign the value `0.0` when needed. One could also use an `else` instead of the `except`, however, that would be poor practice as it would catch too broad a spectrum of errors (for instance, if the read itself fails, that's a more serious issue).

Also, unless you need a particular value for `pi`, Python conveniently offers the following:

```
from math import pi
```

Comment: In the process of float(raw_input("Enter radius: ")), there would not be TypeErrors because raw_input always convert the input into string, right? @BobChao87

Comment: @AmilaPasan That is correct. I may have been a bit over-zealous in looking for errors that could occur. I think it demonstrates a good lesson on how to handle multiple errors, so I'll leave it in and point out that it's not quite strictly needed.